# Using pyplot pcolor for a heatmap, need to add subtotals

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas data frame with values:

```
[[7.86,  0.25,  2.87,  1.09,  27.09]
[ 0.54,  0.0,   0.44,  0.49,   2.03],
[ 5.34,  0.79,  2.32,  0.54,   3.76],
[ 2.22,  0.49,  0.79,  0.2,    0.3 ],
[31.98,  0.89,  2.62,  0.15,   4.94]]
```

I'm calling matplotlib with:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(d.index), 1), d.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(d.columns), 1), d.columns)
c = plt.pcolor(d, cmap="PuBu")
show_values(c)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

And getting this result:
[image: pyplot heatmap]

What I need to do, and I can't find documentation, is show the subtotals for each row and column of this matrix on the axes. I don't know if there's a specific option or if I need to add 10/11 annotations to it.

Comment: `ax.annotate` + blended transfroms are probably the way to go here.